# Scaling Car Model

Tags: transforms

i have a car model and i want to convert my model to toy car like LNCLN WRKS models.

That is what i want...

[image]

When i am scaling my object in one direction, fender part of the car is also scaling like this...

[image]

but i want to scale my object in one direction when the fender and tire parts of the car remain constant like this...

[image]

Is there any way to solve it? Thank you for your support...

Comment: you have to separate the tires first so that they won't be scaled. But of course you have to remodel parts of the car as well like the fender

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your support...

Comment: Select everything in Edit mode then deselect the part that you don't want to scale?

Comment: @moonboots hello. i tried it but when i do this, the positions of unselected parts remain constant. other parts are getting closing in one direction. the unselected parts should be also get close in one direction...

Comment: There's no other soluction than to scale the parts you want, then move the unselected parts so that they are closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, what you are trying to do here is not really "scaling". At least not scaling the whole car.

Scaling is defined as modifying or altering size of an object. So if your tyres are part of the object you are scaling, (of course) they are going to get scaled too.

One solution to your problem is to do as @Moonboots says which is separate the tyres to their own objects, scale the car separately and then reposition the tyres.

If somehow, you don't like that solution, or need some more "accurate" method, I can suggest you [vertex parenting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#vertex-parent-from-object-mode). It allows you to parent an object to one (or more) vetex of another object and you could do something like this :

[image: Scaling the object with vertex parenting]

This setup is very easy to do. You can see the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#vertex-parent-from-object-mode).

Comment: Please note that, the model in the example is a very simlple model but for a complicated model (like a car in you case), things may not exactly look the way you want them after scaling so you may end up repositionning the tyres anyway.

Comment: Thank you very very much. That is what i trying to find. :)

Comment: You're welcome.